# Use jquery to animate the Fill of an SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I am trying to use jQuery to animate the path of my SVG, THEN after the first animation completes, animate the fill of the SVG with a duration and an easing function.

Is this possible?

```
$(function() {
  $('svg').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce')
      .css('fill', '#f4321e');
      console.log('on');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 900}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce')
      .css('fill', 'none');
  });
});
```

thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes you can. jQuery doesn't animate colors, but jQuery UI and various plugins do.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io/) or [greensock](https://greensock.com/)

Comment: @Mi-Creativity, yes I have tried it but it does not animate it.

Comment: When you said "*Is this possible?*"  I thought you asked without trying it, this why

Comment: @adeneo  - still dont see how i can use it for color fill, maybe with the `element.classList.add('newclass')`

@Mi-Creativity - I have seen of them but looking into Snapsvg i haven't found any good Docs or examples. Il checkout GSAP.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity,   ohhh gotcha, yeah im not one of those guys unless im completely clueless of the subject... haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by using CSS transition <sup>(*)</sup>, *but* you need to make the `fill:transparent` instead of `fill:none`, like below <sup>(1)</sup>:

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/evotmrwx/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('svg').hover(function() {
    $('svg').find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, 1000)
      .css({'fill': 'red', 'transition': 'fill 1s'});
    console.log('on');
  }, function() {
    $('svg').find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 900}, 1000)
      .css({'fill': 'transparent', 'transition': 'fill 1s'});
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="orange" class="social-circle" />
</svg>
```

---

Also you can make use of the callback function which the [**`.animate()`**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function provides

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Where "`complete` is a function to *call once the animation is complete*, called once per matched element", we can here call another function that animates fill of the element using CSS **[`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)** like this:

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/evotmrwx/2/)

```js
$(function() {

  $('svg').hover(function() {
    $('svg').find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, 1000, animateFill('red'))
    console.log('on');
  }, function() {
    $('svg').find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 900}, 1000, animateFill('transparent'))
  });


  function animateFill(theColor) {
    $('svg').find('.social-circle').css({'fill': theColor, 'transition': 'fill 1s'});
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="orange" class="social-circle" />
</svg>
```

---

---

Alternatively you can achieve the same effect with [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) -*which supports* IE9+ *while CSS transition is supported by* IE10 *and above*- using its **[`animate()`](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.animate)** <sup>(*)</sup> function, but when I tried to pass `animFill('transparent')` or `animFill('none')` it defaults the color to black rather than transparent. So I made the function animates both the `fill` and the `fill-opacity` <sup>(2)</sup> so it could be used for both transitioning colors or fill opacity. as following:

[**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/jvxt0p1v/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('svg').hover(function() {
    $('svg').find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, 1000, animFill('red', 1));
    console.log('on');
  }, function() {
    $('svg').find('.social-circle').stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 900}, 1000, animFill('red', 0))
  });
});

function animFill(theColor, theOpacity) {
  Snap('svg').select('.social-circle')
    .animate({'fill': theColor,'fill-opacity': theOpacity}, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="orange" class="social-circle" id="social" />
</svg>
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(*)</sup> *For both CSS transition and Snap.svg animation you can use easing just like jQuery. For CSS it could be done like this*:

```
transition: fill 1s ease-out
```

*For Snap.svg the easing could be set through the [**`mina()`**](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#mina) method, same as above*:

```
element.animate({'fill':theColor, 'fill-opacity':theOpacity}, 1000, mina.easeout);
```

<sup>(1)</sup> *I removed the easing for simplicity*.

<sup>(2)</sup> *By using `fill-opacity` we control the opacity of the `fill` only, if we use `opacity`, the whole element will be affected as `fill` and `stroke`. And there's `stroke-opacity` as well for controlling the opacity of the stroke too*.